# Wordpress Woocommerce shop page: modal with swiper to view products - how to improve load speed?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, woocommerce

On the Woocommerce shop page, I would like each product page to open in a Bootstrap modal when clicking the view button. Within that modal, I want to implement Swiper JS so that all products can be viewed within the modal.

Here is the concept: https://codepen.io/sophmek/pen/dyOQqRE

I have implemented this concept in Wordpress already but the problem is the loading speed - it takes quite a while for the correct slide to appear or for the swiper to initialize sometimes.

How can I improve loading speed?

Here is my Wordpress code:

functions.php - here I just add the product ID to the link, which I use in the script

```
  add_action( 'woocommerce_after_shop_loop_item', 'add_custom_button', 10, 0 );
   function add_custom_button() {
   $productid = wc_get_product()->get_id();
   echo '<a data-id="'.$productid.'" class="view-post button alt btn-sample openBtn">View</a>';
  }
```

archive-product.php

```
  <?php
//get the ids
 $ids = get_posts( array(
 'posts_per_page' => -1,
 'post_type' => array('product','product_variation'),
 'fields' => 'ids',
  ) );
 
 ?>

<div class="modal woo fade" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog woo">
    <div class="modal-content">
         <div class="modal-header">
             <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
         </div>
         <div class="modal-body">

 <!-- swiper starts -->
        <div class="swiper-container woo">
        <div class="swiper-wrapper">

<?php

//within the modal, I need all the slides
foreach ($ids as $id) {

echo '<div class="swiper-slide" id="slide-'. $id .'">';

 $args = array(
     'p' => $id,
     'post_type' => 'product',
     'posts_per_page' => -1,
     'orderby' => 'menu_order',
     );

 $loop = new WP_Query( $args );
 if ( $loop->have_posts() ) {
     while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
         wc_get_template_part( 'content', 'single-product' );
     endwhile;
 } else {
     echo __( 'No products found' );
 }
 wp_reset_postdata();

 echo '</div>';

} 

?>
</div>
<div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-prev"></div>
<div class="swiper-button-next"></div>

</div>
<!-- swiper ends -->

 </div>
    </div>
       <div class="modal-footer">
             <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
     </div>
 </div>
```

Script

```
 <script>

 jQuery(document).ready(function($){

     $('.openBtn').on('click',function(){
             //collect id from link
              id =  $(this).data("id"); 
              $('.modal.woo').modal('show');

     $(".modal.woo").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
            //connect to correct slide in swiper
             sliderid = $('#slide-'+id).data("swiper-slide-index"); 

        setTimeout(function () {

         swiper = new Swiper(".swiper-container.woo", {

            on: {
                 init: function () {
                     console.log('swiper initialized'); 
                 },
                 },
            initialSlide: sliderid, //initial slide based on id
            loop: true,
            autoHeight: true,

            pagination: {
                el: ".swiper-pagination"
            },

            navigation: {
                nextEl: ".swiper-button-next",
                prevEl: ".swiper-button-prev"
            },

            scrollbar: {
                el: ".swiper-scrollbar"
            }

        });

    }, 5000);
    });
    });
  });

  </script>
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging with the network tool on devtools? What is the slowdown, front end or serverside?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I am looking into this now (have to figure out how to do this properly first). I have noticed another problem though: the first time you open the modal, the swiper does not initialize and the correct slide does not show. In the codepen, it works when you click on View two times. In Wordpress, it works after the third time.

Comment: Update: the initializing problem is fixed by closing the .btn function before the show.bs.modal function starts. I have updated the pen and it works for me. Stilll looking into the main issue